# How can I use Hebrew page numbering for a few pages in an English document?

Tags: page-numbering, hebrew

I am using `polyglossia`.

I want one or two pages to use Hebrew and have Hebrew page numbering (and the Hebrew page numbering to appear in the ToC).

I know that if the default language is Hebrew, and you add `[numerals=hebrew]` to the declaration, then `\pagenumbering{alph}` will give the pages Hebrew page numbering, but my document is mostly in English.

I know I can use `\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}` to create a few pages in Hebrew, but in those pages `\pagenumbering{alph}` still uses the English alphabet. For instance, the page in the following code will be numbered as "a".

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Hebrew]
\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}[numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}
\pagenumbering{alph}    
\setcounter{page}{1}          
דיכאון עמוק
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to add a few Hebrew page numbers to a mostly English document?

Answer (score 2):

The header and footer are deliberately made independent of any environment that may be going on in the text area  including `otherlanguage`.  This solution creates a new page style (hebrew) which implements the `otherlanguage` environment in the footer.

Note that if the page style is started after `\begin{otherlanguage}` it will revert the moment `\end{otherlanguage}` occurs, which means the last footer will be in arabic.  If the page style is started before `\begin{otherlanguage}` then it will remain in effect until `\pagestyle{plain}` (for example) is used.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Hebrew]

\makeatletter
\def\ps@hebrew{%
  \let\@oddhead\relax
  \let\@evenhead\relax
  \def\@oddfoot{\hfill\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}%
    \hebrewnumeral{\arabic{page}}%
    \end{otherlanguage}\hfill}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{hebrew}   
\begin{otherlanguage}[numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}    
דיכאון עמוק
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It only half works. The page number at the bottom of the page is "א", but the ToC still lists it as page "1".

Comment: One can modify \thepage to use \hebrewnumeral{\arabic{page}}, but sometimes it is used immediately and sometimes it isn't expanded until shipout.  You may have to modify whatever is writing to the ToC.

Comment: I eventually did it by directly changing the toc file and replacing the \tableofcontents command with \input XXX.toc. Crude, but effective.

Comment: @DoronBenHadar Hell NO! This is a very bad idea.

Comment: See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
\documentclass{report}

\title{Page Number Example}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage{hebfont}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
{   \Huge
    A page with no numbering
    \thispagestyle{empty}
}

\newpage
{   \Huge
    A page with roman numerals
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
}

\newpage
{   \Huge
    A page with Latin letters
    \pagenumbering{alph}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
}

\newpage
{   \Huge
    A page with Arabic numerals
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
}



\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\newpage
{   \Huge
    עמוד עם אותיות עבריות
    \pagenumbering{alph}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

See @john-kormoly answer for numbering.To solve toc thing:

In the beginning

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}
```

In the right place

```
\robustify{\thepage}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\thepage{\texthebrew{\protect\hebrewnumeral{1}}}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Hebrew something}
```

Maybe `page` will work too.